# How operating 32Bit Excel from 64bit EXE

Tags: .net, excel, visual-studio, vsto

I was able to operate 32bit Excel using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel from an application built on x64.
I often see that it has to be a 32-bit EXE, but no problem?

Is PIA doing the conversion for us?

windows 10 20H2,
.net framerowk ver 4.6.2,
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ver 15.0.0.0

Comment: It was some time ago I used Interop. But I think it runs excel in a separate process and uses COM to communicate with it. Since it is different processes, no problem with 32/64 bitness.

Answer (score 0):

No conversion necessary - all Office apps (Excel included) are exposed as out-of-proc COM servers, so the bitness does not have to match: you can access 32 bit Excel from a 64 bit process.

Both 32 and 64 bit versions of Office apps expose the same type library (whcih the interop dll wraps), it is not bitness specific.